# Why random integer is outputed when more '%' conversions than data arguments error occurs in c?

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior

I take out the age variable from the `printf()` call just to see what happens. I then compile it with make. It seems it only throws warning about more % conversions than data arguments and unused age variable but no compile error. I then run the executable file and it does run. Only every time I run it, it returns different random integer. I'm wondering what causes this behavior?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *arg[]) {
  int age = 10;
  int height = 72;

  printf("I'm %d years old\n");
  printf("I'm %d inches tall\n", height);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might not get a compiler error, but I would almost guarantee you get a compiler *warning*.  Get in the habit of paying attention to those if you expect to do much C programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the `printf()` specification, if there are insufficient number of arguments for the required format specifier, it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

So, your code

```
printf("I'm %d years old\n");
```

which is missing the required argument for `%d`, invokes UB and not guaranteed to produce any valid result.

Cross reference, `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.1

> [..] If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined. [..]

Comment: This is 100% correct, I think this is a good case to illustrate to a new programmer why it's absolutely vital in C to read compiler warnings and often helpful to crank up the verbosity, e.g. with GCC `-Wall`.  Any decent modern compiler will warn about this particular problem by default.

Comment: Yeah yeah, this is correct and all, but I dislike the idea of dismissing on account of undefined behavior. Isn't it more interesting to know what *is* happening, as illustrated in one of the other answers?

Comment: @Purag I understand, but what _is_ happening is **not guaranteed** in general, and heavily dependent on platform and not at all covered by the `C` standard.

Comment: I think there could be a great answer here that discusses why there's a random number there (it has to come from somewhere!) *and* discourages using `printf` this way due to undefined behavior (and the possibility of crashing your program if you're not so lucky...)

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function - the same is valid for printf)

> 2. ...**If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined.** If the format is exhausted while arguments
>      remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are
>      otherwise ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The printf using cdecl, which using stack arguments. If you implied to the function that you are using one argument, it will be pulled out of the runtime stack, and if you didn't put there your number, the place will probably contain some garbage data. So the argument which will be printed is some arbitrary data.

Answer (score 0):

With only one exception I know of, the C Standard imposes no requirements with regard to any action which in some plausible implementations might be usefully trapped.  It is not hard to imagine a C compiler passing a variadic function like `printf` an indication of what arguments it has passed, nor would it be hard to an implementer thinking that it could be useful to have the compiler trigger a trap if code tries to retrieve a variadic parameters of some type when the corresponding argument is some other type or doesn't exist at all.  Because it could be useful to have compilers trap in such cases, and because the behavior of such a trap would be outside the jurisdiction of the Standard, the Standard imposes no requirements about what may or may not happen when a variadic function tries to receive arguments which weren't passed to it.

In practice, rather than letting variadic functions know how many arguments they've received, most compilers simply have conventions which describe a relationship between the location of the non-variadic argument and the locations of subsequent variadic arguments.  The generated code won't know whether a function has received e.g. two arguments of type `int`, but it will know that each such argument, *if it exists*, will be stored in a certain place.  On such a compiler, using excess format specifiers will generally result in the generated code looking at the places where additional arguments would have been stored had they existed.  In many cases, this location will have been used for some other purpose and then abandoned, and may hold the last value stored there for that purpose, but there is generally no reason to expect anything in particular about the contents of abandoned memory.